# Metric with a constant Chern–Pontryagin scalar

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Do there exist 3+1 dimensional spacetimes (i.e. Lorentzian manifolds with signaure (1,3)), for which the Chern–Pontryagin scalar
\begin{equation}
K_2= \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\mu\nu}R^{\beta}{}_{\alpha\rho\sigma}\,,
\end{equation}
is a non-zero constant? $R^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\mu\nu}$ is Riemann's curvature tensor and $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ is the contravariant Levi-Civita tensor.

To be specific, I would be interested in finding a metric of such a spacetime.

In 3+1 dimensional theories of chiral (Weyl) fermions in a curved space-time, $K_2$ is at source of gravitational anomaly -- a violation of charge conservation, where particles are produced at a rate proportional to $K_2$ ([Jensen, K., Loganayagam, R. & Yarom, A. Thermodynamics, gravitational anomalies and cones](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP02(2013)088)). In chiral anomaly, a closely related phenomenon due to gauge fields, particle production rate is proportional to $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}=\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B}$, for which it's very easy to find a case where it's constant and non-zero.

My best effort so far was to find a power-series perturbation around a Minkowski spacetime in Cartesian coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 y^2-y z-z^2+1 & y^2-z^2 & 0 & 0 \\
 y^2-z^2 & y^2-y z-z^2-1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,,
\end{equation}
for which
\begin{equation}
K_2=\frac{32 \left(y z \left(2 y^2-y z-2 z^2\right)-1\right)}{\left(y z \left(2 y^2-y z-2 z^2\right)+1\right)^{5/2}}
= -32 + O\left((y^2+z^2)^2\right)\,.
\end{equation}
I can push the calculation to higher orders, but I'm not too hopeful in finding a closed-form expression this way.

Comment: Won't this expression be constant for any homogeneous spacetime?  Are you requiring anything else, such as completeness or asymptotic flatness or some such condition?

Comment: Indeed you're right, I meant constant and non-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{A}{(1-t z)^2 (x y-1)^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{A}{(1-t z)^2 (x y-1)^2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,.
\end{equation}
The Chern-Pontryagin scalar is $K_2 = -16/|A|$ for $xy>1,tz>1$.

**Update:** Under a conformal transformation $g'=\Omega g$, the Chern-Pontryagin scalar transforms as $K_2' = K_2/\Omega^2$, so for any metric with a non vanishing $K_2$, one can take $\Omega = \sqrt{|K_2|}$ and produce a metric, for which it's constant.